# vuex axios multiple API calls

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuex

I am trying to make multiple API calls to themovieDB API using Axios in vue2. My vuex module looks like this and it works just fine and I have access to the getter getMovieData in all the components that needs access to the getMovieData getter:
Only when the Promise.all will resolve the setMovies mutation will set the movie data in the store. I will then use the getMovieData in different components in my vue application. My main question is, is this kind of a bad habit to make this many API calls and have that long of an action (fetchMovieData) or should I break it down in smaller pieces? Is there a better way to make API calls to the movie DB API when you need to get for example different genres from the API? As you can see I have made multiple API calls and made an array of objects with the data that I need in different components.

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  state: {
    movieData: [
      {
        showcaseMovie: [],
        popular: [],
        action: [],
        comedy: [],
        crime: [],
        documentary: [],
        drama: [],
        horror: [],
        sciFi: [],
      },
    ],
  },

  getters: {
    getMovieData: (state) => {
      return state.movieData[0];
    },
  },

  mutations: {
    setMovies(
      state,
      {
        showcase,
        popular,
        action,
        comedy,
        crime,
        documentary,
        drama,
        horror,
        sciFi,
      }
    ) {
      state.movieData[0].showcaseMovie = showcase;
      state.movieData[0].popular = popular;
      state.movieData[0].action = action;
      state.movieData[0].comedy = comedy;
      state.movieData[0].crime = crime;
      state.movieData[0].documentary = documentary;
      state.movieData[0].drama = drama;
      state.movieData[0].horror = horror;
      state.movieData[0].sciFi = sciFi;
    },
  },

  actions: {
    fetchMovieData({ commit, state }) {
      const apiUrl = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/';
      const apiKey = 'demoAPI';
      const genresUrl =
        'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=&language=en-US&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1&with_genres=';

      Promise.all([
        axios
          .get(
            `${apiUrl}find/tt4667888?api_key=${apiKey}&language=en-US&external_source=imdb_id`
          )
          .then((response) => response.data),
        axios
          .get(`${apiUrl}trending/all/day?api_key=${apiKey}`)
          .then((response) => response.data.results),

        axios.get(`${genresUrl}28`).then((response) => response.data.results),
        axios.get(`${genresUrl}35`).then((response) => response.data.results),
        axios.get(`${genresUrl}80`).then((response) => response.data.results),
        axios.get(`${genresUrl}99`).then((response) => response.data.results),
        axios.get(`${genresUrl}18`).then((response) => response.data.results),
        axios.get(`${genresUrl}27`).then((response) => response.data.results),
        axios.get(`${genresUrl}878`).then((response) => response.data.results),
      ])

        .then(
          ([
            showcase,
            popular,
            action,
            comedy,
            crime,
            documentary,
            drama,
            horror,
            sciFi,
          ]) => {
            commit('setMovies', {
              showcase,
              popular,
              action,
              comedy,
              crime,
              documentary,
              drama,
              horror,
              sciFi,
            });
            console.log(state.movieData);
          }
        )
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: If you get too many users you might hit some rate limit that API has. If you have a backend you can do the complex request there, let's say once every 10min to keep the data fresh. Then your Vue app can just do 1 request to your own backend.

Comment: @Mellet Thank you for your answer. This API currently doesn't have a rate limit and since  im only doing this as a demo project for my front end portfolio I currently don't have any back end skills.

Comment: Depending on your UX/UI, you may want to split up your API calls by genre, and then 'lazy load' call them as needed e.g. do not make the 'comedy' call until a user specifies comedy.  First you check to see if the comedy data has been initialized.  If not, then make the comedy API call.